# Integer to scientific notation

Tags: powershell

I needed to convert a large integer to and between exponential notation (or e notation), and all questions was about converting **from** exponential notation.

Which is easy, just enter the number as is, ie. ***2.57588E13*** and powershell will automatically convert it for you.

However, to get it back might not be obvious and had to resort to C# forums to finally find the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
$bignumber = 2.57588E13
Write-Output "Result: $bignumber"
25758800000000

Write-Output $bignumber.tostring("e5")
2.57588e+013
```

The "e" is the number of decimals that should be visible in the result. Hope this helps someone else.